# How to have IBAction happen on start of iPad app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, ibaction

I have an `IBAction` command in my **iPad** app that I would like to invoke when the app first starts.

What code can I use to do this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try the `viewDidLoad` method of your firstViewController to call your method using `[self METHODNAME:nil];`

This will call the method on application start automatically

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

IBAction is nothing but a way for interface builder to know which method it can call.
So if you want to call an IBAction, call that method directly.

Comment: More over `IBAction` is a typedef of `void`. So call the method directly from your code or from `viewDidLoad:`

Answer (score 1):

If your method is called `- (IBAction)myAction:(id)sender`
you can just call `[self myAction:nil];` from wherever you like.

Answer (score -1):

If you need to invoke a command on app launch,, call the method from viewDidLoad of your firstViewController. IBAction is basically used when you have to take user input.

Comment: better use a method in app delegate than a method that can be called multiple times like `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: yeah sure, that depends on the requirement, if it is required once then app delegate is a better option.